# Event trigger - Best practices

Tags: c#, events, parallel-processing, event-handling

My program collects data from various sensors and whenever there is something wrong with the sensor reading, then I have to send an email to alert the user.

For this, I have assigned a variable SEND_MSG to trigger the email send event. Whenever there is something off with the reading, I set SEND_MSG to 999 and another thread, which loops and checks this variable triggers the send email process. Read/Write operation of the SEND_MSG occurs inside a lock statement.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are polling a variable holding status from a thread to communicate state. That's not a very efficient design.

There are a number of inter-thread communication mechanisms that handle this situation much more elegantly.

For a great overview of mechanisms see http://www.albahari.com/threading/

If you simply want to communicate the need to send an email, you can use for example an [AutoResetEvent](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_AutoResetEvent).

Another option, which makes it easy to communicate additional information such as the sensor number, type of malfunction, etc., you can consider using a [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx). There's a good example of how to use it at the bottom of that link.